# Computer does not automatically boot from the hard disk

Tags: windows, boot, bios

When I start my computer, it does not boot from the hard disk. When I select "hard disk" by pressing `F10` while booting, it correctly boots to Windows.

I have a DG41RQ board and a SATA hardisk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two possibilities: you either need to change your boot sequence in order to correctly boot Windows, or you have to update your [`BIOS`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS).

### Editing the boot sequence

When you turn on your computer press the key associated with "setup" on the first splash screen you get — usually <kbd>Del</kbd> or <kbd>F2</kbd>. Now navigate through the `BIOS` settings and try to find a menu called "Boot sequence" or something similar.

In this menu you can change the boot sequence, make sure your hard drive is on top. Save, exit and reboot. If this worked for you, then you don not need to perform the other step.

For more information on changing the boot sequence, check out [this About.com guide](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/ss/bootorderchange.htm).

### Updating the `BIOS`

It could be that your problems are caused by old firmware on your motherboard. In order to determine if this might fix the problem you are having we first need to find out the current version of the installed `BIOS` firmware.

Hit <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, type `msinfo32` and press enter. Look under "Processor" and make a note of the installed `BIOS` version. Now check your manufacturers website for `BIOS` updates, if there are none, your story ends here.

If there is a patch available, **first RTFM** and follow any instruction to install the patch.

For more information on updating the `BIOS`, check out [this PC World article](http://www.pcworld.com/article/187437/how_to_update_your_bios.html).

Answer (score 0):

I have also same problem but I replace hard disk PCB board then my PC boot automatically. And you find which part problem in PC you just remove your HDD and then start your PC Without pressing any key like F2 DEL etc  you showing message select boot device properly then faulty your hard disk other then can't show any other error.

Comment: Your problem with a bad HDD PCB might also produce similar symptoms, but that is a pretty rare cause for this problem.  There are plenty of other things to look at before replacing the PCB.  I removed your email address because it isn't appropriate on Super User and it would be a spam magnet for you.  After the first sentence, your answer is hard to follow (I'm guessing English isn't your first language).  I couldn't understand it well enough to reword your point.  Can you see if you can clarify it?

Answer (score 0):

I Had a problem where my pc wasn't detecting the cpu fan and there was an option in the bios to wait for f1 ( f1 for me is to go into the bios) if there is an error before booting into windows. Make sure there are no errors being displayed.